# Multiple calls to Oracle WITH statement

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I've been asked to refactor an Oracle report, a DB that I'm not that familiar with. Part of the query has been running slowly and a context-switch has been identified. It was suggested that I use a `WITH` clause to replace the use of a cursor which I've done:

e.g.

```
   WITH MyData AS
   (
      SELECT * FROM People WHERE Age < 60;
   )
   SELECT * FROM MyData
```

My problem is that I want to call MyData multiple times in the script but I can't work out how to do this using `WITH` clause. During researching this I've found a few articles that mention that the `WITH` clause can use global temporary tables by using the `MATERIALIZE` hint.

My question is this: Is it possible to call a WITH clause multiple times? If not, will I still see a performance improvement from using global temporary tables instead?

Comment: Only within the same query, e.g. in both parts of a `union`. Sounds like you maybe want to select into a (schema-level-defined) table collection, which you can then reference in later queries. Without seeing what the current PL/SQL is doing though it's hard to know why it's causing a performance issue, or how best to fix it. Maybe you have nested cursors, which could be rewritten as a single (perhaps complicated) query instead. How were context switches identified as the bottleneck?

Comment: When you say "call MyData multiple times in the script" I assume you mean that you want to use the data in multiple different SQL statements rather than wanting to reference `MyData` multiple times in the same SQL statement.  You could, of course, put the `WITH` clause on each query that needs it.  Even if each query had the same `WITH` clause, Oracle would need to access the data separately for each query.  You could benchmark whether it makes sense to store the data in a collection or a temporary table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WITH` clause is supposed to be called multiple times within one SQL statement, not within one sql script / plsql block. Like this:

```
WITH MyData AS
   (
      SELECT * FROM People WHERE Age < 60;
   )
   SELECT * FROM MyData WHERE AGE = 10
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM MyData WHERE AGE = 20
```

In some cases optimizer will inline calls to `MyData` and re-execute the query. In other cases (one of them being a `materialize` hint) it will implicitly create a temporary table for the results of the `SELECT * FROM People WHERE Age < 60` query and select from that table onwards - but again - these temporary tables exist only for duration of the query that implicitly created them.

If you're on 10g and don't want to re-execute your `MyData` query multiple times - temp table is your option.

Comment: Thanks, I'd suspected so.  I'd been confused when researching this that materialise used a temp table, I took that to mean it could be accessed further along. I'll re-write using a temp table.

Comment: Will a GTT solve a 'context switching' bottleneck though? Not sure how a single cursor being replaced is going to make much difference. Unless the same cursor is being opened and iterated over multiple times, I suppose.

Comment: @AlexPoole indeed it won't, but as long as OP didn't provide enough details to address his performance issue as a whole, my answer was mostly supposed to clarify that `with` confusion.

Comment: Just for clarity, a Common Table Expression (the WITH clause) does not actually create a temporary table per se, but it can write the result set to a temporary segment in the same way that a global temporary table writes to a temporary segment.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of extra detail. The script I 'inherited' is a lengthly mess and I couldn't really post it either in full or in part. I'm hoping the GTT will reduce the bottleneck a bit. Ideally, I'd re-write the lot but this should be the last time it'll be used so it's not worth the time. Thanks for all your input.